# Using Polynomial Regression in Excel

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010, dynamic-programming, trendline

Suppose I have a set of X's and Y's(both numneric data) which is dynamic i.e. changes based on certain conditions.
Using those two sets of data a scatter plot is prepared with a polynomial trendline of degree 3. I have also called for its equation and now I want to utilise that dynamic equation for my further calculations.

How to use the formula of that trendline in calculations?

Answer (score 0):

From: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2019/01/16/excel-trendline-types-equations-formulas/

By Svetlana Cheusheva

> Equation: y = b<sub>3</sub>x<sup>3</sup> + b<sub>2</sub>x<sup>2</sup>+ b<sub>1</sub>x + a
>
> b<sub>3</sub>: =INDEX(LINEST(y, x^{1,2,3}), 1)
>
> b<sub>2</sub>: =INDEX(LINEST(y, x^{1,2,3}), 1, 2)
>
> b<sub>1</sub>: =INDEX(LINEST(y, x^{1,2,3}), 1, 3)
>
> a: =INDEX(LINEST(y, x^{1,2,3}), 1, 4)

One cannot reference the trendline formula on the graph directly, but one can use the formulas above to get the parts needed to use with the regression analysis.